# Can't get facebook pictures without token on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am able to access a user picture in a web browser without providing an access token, using the url:
http://graph.facebook.com/ID/picture

I know it performs a redirection, but it works.

However, when trying to access the same url in an iOS HttpRequest, I get an "invalid_token" response.

Is it possible to get a picture from an ID, in iOS without a token? If so, how do I achieve this? If not, how is it possible using the web browser?

Thanks!

Comment: I've edited your question to remove the tags from the title. Please note that you don't need to include them there - just use the tag system :-)

Comment: Hmm... I see what you mean, but I've also seen tags in titles around, and without them, in this case, the title alone is very unfocused. I'm guessing the question is also less likely to be found via google (which is how I usually eventually reach SO). I respect your rep :), but are you sure about it?

Comment: I'm very sure. There's a question on meta somewhere about it, the consensus is that tags only work in titles if they form a natural part of the wording; just appending or prepending them doesn't work and tags are much more useful. I don't think it would change the search rankings either - I'd bet that SO has some decent SEO that uses the tags as well as the title for page metadata anyway.

Comment: [Found the link!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Comment: You definitely win. Thanks for the edit and link! ... now, I could still use an answer... happen to know anything on the topic? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is stuck with this, apparently under some conditions you get an "invalid token" response from the facebook (graph api) if you use a POST and not a GET http request method. Switching to GET solved the problem for me.